# iWork Keynote: Automate video export with custom settings for multiple files

Tags: macos, bash, export, iwork-keynote

I have a couple of Apple iWork Keynote presentations and exporting it to Quicktime with my customized settings from within Keynote is straightforward.

But here's my problem:
How do I manage to automate the video export so that I can initiate the export for a set of Keynote files at once? This would save me lots of time and repetitive mouse clicks.
The holy grail for me would be a bash command like

> for file in *.key; do KEYNOTE -export quicktime -settings mysettings $file; done

I can't find anything like that though.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you will have more success using AppleScript or Automator for tasks like these. Try recording a script while you do your actions and see what it gives you, then you can apply that script to a watch folder or set of files that you drag and drop.

Comment: I think you should combine some bash commands with AppleScript (AS). Regarding the AS part, check if you can adapt some ideas from [this blog](http://lithium3141.com/2013/05/28/applescripting-keynote-pdf-export/) or [this file from github](https://github.com/techjobalert/communities/blob/master/src/keynote_to_mov.applescript). Looking forward to hear from you!